# Quorum :- metamask do not support privateFor feature of quorum

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, metamask, quorum

i got to know that metamask do not support privateFor because  of which private transaction for quorum dapp was not behaving as expected. so, I can't use metamask for my quorum DApp to switch port and address. Is there any other wallet that support privateFor if not please suggest how can I change port and account address from DApp level?